# Counting the number of cells in a formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I’m trying to determine a way to count the number of cell locations in a given formula.

For example, a cell (let’s say a1) contains the following: `=c1+d3+f11+g5`.

In a different cell (let’s say a2) the outcome would be 4 in this example.

Whenever a1 changes, a2 would update to the new count of total cell locations in the formula.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does [Count How Many Cells are Referenced in a Formula in Excel](https://yacostasolutions.com/count-cells-in-formula/) answer your. Why did you not find this when searching for an answer?

Comment: Will all of the referenced cells be on the same worksheet as the formula?  Or might there be some on a different worksheet?

Comment: For a more comprehensive method, take a look at [this](https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/vba-determine-all-precedent-cells-a-nice-example-of-recursion/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DavidPostill Just to clarify, the number of *arguments* in a function call is not at all the same problem as the number of cell references in a formula.  The latter problem is profoundly more complicated, and cannot be solved by the approach in your link.

Comment: This gets a whole lot easier if your formulas will only be addition and nothing else.  It gets a fair amount more complicated if you want to include addition, multiplication, subtraction, division.  And it starts to get “other-worldly” level of complicated if you want additional operators and functions.  Tell us what the limits to the formula will be in terms of numbers of cell references, range of operators, and complexity.  Also, this may be a much harder problem to solve if you are limited to Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=LEN(FORMULATEXT(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"+",""))+1
```

[image]